# Identify the Master Server in an Active Directory listing

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, password

I have recently inherited a database server that the previous developers appear to have lost the Admin password for it.  Speaking to the hosting providers they keep telling me that as it is a dedicated server which has had active directory installed they are unable to reset the password as it needs to be done on the Master Server.

I have 2 other servers provided by the hosting company and I would have thought these would have been the master server to the active directoy listing, but they do not seem to be so, neither has active directory installed on it.

Is there a way to find out the master server for a network / active directory?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can identify the active directory server by executing the following steps from the domain computers that are configured within it:

`start > cmd > echo %LOGONSERVER%`

Comment: thank you for your reply, just to clarify that will tell me the master server?

Comment: yes it will tell you the name of the master server/active directory server depending upon the domain you logonto